# how i get the name of user who logged in my website now django

Tags: django, django-views, django-users

```
def show(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('location') and request.POST.get('member') and request.POST.get('arrival') and request.POST.get('leaving'):
            dest = Destination()
            dest.location = request.POST.get('location')
            dest.member = request.POST.get('member')
            dest.arrival = request.POST.get('arrival')
            dest.leaving = request.POST.get('leaving')
            dest.author = user.name(User.objects.all())
            dest.save()
            messages.success(request, 'we will send you best option..!')
            return render(request,'travell/home.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'travell/home.html')
```

what should i do in author please help i am new in this

Comment: Please, add the Destination model code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want `request.user.name` (if your User model has a `name` field).

Better yet would be to have a real foreign key field to your user model instead of just a name field.